# Static variable in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, static-variables

I am writing a code for a webapplication in vb.net. I am using a shared variable in the vb code.

Consider the static variable value is 3 for a user who hits the web application. Again when another user hits the same web application, whether the static variable will be 3 again or whether he will have a separate value for static variable for his session?

Sorry, if the question is too rudumentary.

Answer (score 0):

The static variable will be the same for each session, and also the same for each user.

Static variables have very limited use in web applications, as you don't get one per user, you only get one.